# How to get key path for item in dictionary inside many arrays

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary, nsoutlineview

I have an array contains dictionary and the dictionary contain array so on so on.

How i can get the key path for item inside one of that arrays.

I need this to present hierarchy data (tree) in my database to outlineView, so , i can deal with the firs row in my array by using key path like (parent.children.parent) but the problem when (children) has many items and one of that items has more items ext. how can i look at the pointer to it?

for example:

```
_people = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Person *person = [[Person alloc]initWithName:@"parent" age:36];
[person addChild:[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"child1" age:55]];
[person addChild:[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"child2" age:15]];
[person addChild:[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"child3" age:20]];

[(Person*)[person.childrens objectAtIndex:1] addChild:[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"child1 for child2" age:23]];
[(Person*)[[[person.childrens objectAtIndex:1] childrens] objectAtIndex:0]addChild:[[Person alloc] initWithName:@"last child" age:30]];


[_people addObject:person];
```

Now how i can locate to key for value "last child"

any help please!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the data output , means what response you are getting?

Comment: like parent has a 3 children and the second child has  5 children and fourth one has 3 children .... how to access last child with key path string?

Comment: Put NSLOG in the Response and Post that output here, so it will be easy to understand.

Comment: No output here, i just ask how i can access to the value key in dictionary but this dictionary is inside many arrays?

Comment: I added an example up